# Can we show stock options granted by employer as proof of funds for UK visa?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I have submitted applications for UK standard visitor visa for me, my wife and 2 children. I have bank statements to show as proof of funds and also payslips for proof of income.

I have stock options granted by my employer but only a certain number are actually liquid currently and other options vest later. Should I submit a statement of these   holdings showing their net worth to further improve my application? Note I did not make a mention of these in my visa application as I am not earning any income from these options currently. Is it too late just to submit the documentation and make a mention of this in my cover letter?

Thanks for your prompt advice.

Comment: Stock options have 0 value until they vest at the very least, and more probably until you exercice them. And that’s not just for immigration purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is to provide supporting evidence to substantiate every statement in your application, even if that particular piece of evidence isn’t specifically referred to in the guide https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf

There’s nothing to prevent you from mentioning your stock options in your covering letter, along with an explanation of why you didn’t include them in the application itself.

In case it’s helpful, you should be aware that there is no ‘interview’ for a UK visit visa application; at the biometric appointment you present the checklist and accompanying documents but there will normally not be an opportunity to present or explain anything not already included.